# How to convert HTML values to XML format using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a SELECT HTML element with multiple OPTIONs in it. Using Javascript, onclick of a button i want to show the content(text values of the OPTIONs) in XML format.
I tried to find the answer online but it is all about converting the html to xml file and I am just not sure what should be my approach since i don't want to convert my HTML elements but only the text values inside my OPTION elements should be displayed in xml format.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Include your HTML and a mock-up of the XML you're trying to get, it will be a lot easier for someone to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example that converts a SELECT to XML...  You'll need to change to match the XML output you expect.

```js
function convertSelectToXml(someSelect) {
  var result= [];
  for (var i= 0; i < someSelect.childNodes.length;++i) {
    var item= someSelect.childNodes[i];
    if (item.nodeName === "OPTION") {
      result.push("<item>"+item.innerHTML+"</item>");
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('output').appendChild(document.createTextNode("<items>\n\t"+result.join("\n\t")+"\n</items>"));
}

convertSelectToXml(document.getElementById('mySelect'));
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<pre id="output"/>
```